# uppercase directive not update input angular

Tags: angular

this uppercase directive not work on angular....
if i print a console.log() to see value on format method i can see the value of i input, but the text not update to uppercase on inputText;

my declaration on html

> `<input type="text" uppercase >`

```
import {Directive, Input, Output, EventEmitter, OnInit} from 'angular2/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[uppercase]',
    host: {
        '[value]': 'uppercase',
        '(input)': 'format($event.target.value)'
    }
})
export class Uppercase implements OnInit {

    @Input() uppercase: string;
    @Output() uppercaseChange: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

    constructor() {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.uppercase = this.uppercase || '';
        this.format(this.uppercase);
    }

    format(value) {
        value = value.toUpperCase();
        this.uppercaseChange.next(value);
    }
}
```

how i can do to text uppercase?

Comment: What do you want to archieve exactly. You may need to use your directive in a template or not ? Can you show your template code ?

Comment: hi. I updated the code, I try do it in only one input text         <input type="text" appUppercaseText >

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to update your template like this `<input type="text" uppercase >` in other to apply all changes from your `Directive`.

But it's important to correct your logic because `uppercase` directive will be applied to a `nativeElement` like input.

So you may need to have to implement the **ControlValueAccessor** interface and ajust your directive.

Here a example how you can do this (I have adapted your code): [Uppercase directive on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/uppercase-directive-ng)

I added some comment to the code.

Let me know if it's that what you want to archieve.

---

**Edit (look comments below)**

if you look for a easier way to create your directive and keep the two things you need  *Input text should be Uppercase* and *placeholder should be lowercase*, you can simply do something like following

*uppercase.directive.ts*

```
import { Directive,ElementRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
 selector: '[uppercase]'
})
export class UppercaseDirective {
  constructor(public ref: ElementRef) { }

  @HostListener('input', ['$event']) onInput(event) {
     this.ref.nativeElement.value = event.target.value.toUpperCase();
  }
}
```

*your.template.html*

`<input placeholder="placeholder lowercase" uppercase type='text'>`

I made [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/uppercase-directive-placeholder-lowercase) another demo on stackblitz

Comment: its work, thank you very much, i will study more about ControlValueAccessor

Comment: the placeholder are uppercase to, but i want placeholder lowercase and only value uppercase, you know how solve it?